# Neode connection to Graphenedb on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, graphenedb

I need to connect a node.js project using NEODE library (https://github.com/adam-cowley/neode) to a graphenedb hosted by heroku.

on neode docs they use 2 approaches based on:
1. direct access using
2. env file contains props

Anyone has facing this issue?

```
1. new Neode('bolt://localhost:7687', 'username', 'password', true);

2. // .env
NEO4J_PROTOCOL=bolt
NEO4J_HOST=localhost
NEO4J_USERNAME=neo4j
NEO4J_PASSWORD=neo4j
NEO4J_PORT=7687
```

Answer (score 1):

On Heroku, go to Settings and Reveal Config Vars.

`NEO4J_PROTOCOL` is `bolt`.

`NEO4J_HOST` is Heroku's `GRAPHENE_BOLT_URL` minus the protocol prefix and port suffix, so something like `hobby-sdajflkdjaiodsfajll.dbs.graphenedb.com`

`NEO4J_USERNAME` and `NEO4J_PASSWORD` are `GRAPHENEDB_BOLT_USER` and `GRAPHENEDB_BOLT_PASSWORD` (or whatever username/password you set up on GrapheneDB).

`NEO4J_PORT` is the port from `GRAPHENEDB_BOLT_URL` (24787 default). It is NOT the port from `GRAPHENEDB_URL`.

In your .env file, add `NEO4J_ENCRYPTION=ENCRYPTION_ON`.

As of this writing, there's a [known issue](https://github.com/adam-cowley/neode/issues/111) with Neode not working with Neo4j versions under 4.0 (GrapheneDB runs 3.5) due to multiple database support. If you still want to use Neode, downgrade to v 0.3.7